# How can i fetch a value from a const using a key from another js class n react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, constants

I am able to get to data using a key from a const within a same class, But how can I achieve the same result while placing the const in another js file ? I wanted a value 'Afganistan' while i send a key as '1'.

```
CountryCode.js file: 
  const CountryCode = {
    '1': 'Afghanistan',
    '2': 'Albania',
    '3': 'Algeria',
    '4': 'American Samoa',
    '5': 'Andorra'
  };

HomePage.js file:
  import CountryCode from'./CountryCode';
  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.MainContainer}>

         <Text style={styles.listCountry}>{CountryCode['1']}</Text>

      </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by placing the const in another js file?

Comment: Do you want to print a list of country name on another file?

Comment: I need to get the countries name in many files. So, how can i place in a different file and can get values from another files when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `export default CountryCode` at the end of `CountryCode`

```
 const CountryCode = {
    '1': 'Afghanistan',
    '2': 'Albania',
    '3': 'Algeria',
    '4': 'American Samoa',
    '5': 'Andorra'
  }

export default CountryCode
```

Now the variable should have the value in the other file.

Comment: Thank You !! This is exactly which i was missing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to export data (array) from CountryCode.js file like below.

```
CountryCode.js file: 
  export default {
    '1': 'Afghanistan',
    '2': 'Albania',
    '3': 'Algeria',
    '4': 'American Samoa',
    '5': 'Andorra'
  };
```